# python decorator in flask

Tags: python, decorator, flask

Here is my example:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
def add1(f):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        return str(f(*args, **kwargs))+'1'
    return inner


@app.route('/')
@add1
def hello1():
    return "hello1";

@app.route('/hello2')
@add1
def hello2():
    return "hello2";


if(__name__ =='__main__'):
    app.run()
```

When I run 127.0.0.1:5000, I expect to get "hello11", but I get "hello21", why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that Flask keeps track of the functions by name, and because the functions getting passed to `app.route(path)` are both called `inner`, the second one (`hello2`) overwrites the first. To fix this, you will need the name of the `inner` function to be changed to the name of the function it is decorating. You can change the decorator to

```
def add1(f):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        return str(f(*args, **kwargs))+'1'
    inner.__name__ = f.__name__
    return inner
```

which will work, but is not as elegant as the standard library solution,

```
from functools import wraps

def add1(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        return str(f(*args, **kwargs))+'1'
    return inner
```

The `wraps` decorator not only fixes the name, but the docstring, the file, and the attribute dictionary.

Comment: thanks for the concrete example of the benefits of the official `@wraps`!